# How to parse ShopStyle JSON in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, json, parsing

I have a snippet of some JSON which contains ShopStyle products here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1konfjof33sgNngxIgq_sCyKmCcDda-ziXnOfUUxeKas/edit?usp=sharing

How do I go about getting the products' names and ids from the JSON? So far, I have the following code:

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.shopstyle.com/api/v2/products?pid=%@&fts=%@&offset=0&limit=50", apiKey, searchkeywords]];
NSLog(@"%@", URL);

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:URL] queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        //[self.delegate fetchingGroupsFailedWithError:error];
    } else {
        //[self.delegate receivedGroupsJSON:data];

        NSDictionary *rest_data = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                  options:0
                                                                    error:NULL];

        NSLog(@"rest_data = %@", rest_data);

        for (NSDictionary *topComment in[rest_data objectForKey:@"products"]) {
            [self processCommentThread:topComment andLevel:0];
        }

        NSLog(@"GET COMMENTS RETURN:%@", commentsContainer);
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(doneFormatting) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", rest_data] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}];

/*
PSSProductQuery *productQuery = [[PSSProductQuery alloc] init];
productQuery.searchTerm = searchBar.text;
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

[[PSSClient sharedClient] searchProductsWithQuery:productQuery offset:nil limit:nil success:^(NSUInteger totalCount, NSArray *availableHistogramTypes, NSArray *products) {
    weakSelf.products = products;
    [resultsTableView reloadData];

    NSLog(@"_products = %@", _products);

    resultsTableView.hidden = NO;
} failure:^(int *operation, NSError *error) {
}];
 */

}

- (void)processCommentThread:(NSDictionary *)comments andLevel:(int)level {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSMutableDictionary *comment = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        if (!([comments objectForKey:@"name"] == nil)) {
            [comment setObject:[comments objectForKey:@"name"] forKey:@"name"];
        }
        if (!([comments objectForKey:@"id"] == nil)) {
            [comment setObject:[comments objectForKey:@"id"] forKey:@"id"];
        }
    }
}

-(void)doneFormatting{
    [myTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Looks like plain old JSON.  You parse it with your favorite parser, then peel the resulting data structure like an onion, one layer at a time.

Comment: Note that you need to add debug code to dump what you have at each step along the way.  Otherwise you'll almost certainly make the wrong assumptions about the data structure.

Comment: @HotLicks which parser do you recommend?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with NSJSONSerialization, but you can see your other options at json.org.